# Optimizing twin() method

Tags: java, linked-list

Part III of this [question](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf06/hw/hw3/readme.pdf) says:

> Fill in the `twin()` method in the `SList` class so that it performs as indicated
>   in the comment. Your solution should not use arrays.

Below is the solution written for the `twin()` method in 8 lines of code. Modular testing is done for the `twin()` method.

```
public class SList {

  private SListNode head;
  private int size;

  /**
   *  SList() constructs an empty list.
   **/

  public SList() {
    size = 0;
    head = null;
  }

  /**
   *  isEmpty() indicates whether the list is empty.
   *  @return true if the list is empty, false otherwise.
   **/

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
  }

  /**
   *  length() returns the length of this list.
   *  @return the length of this list.
   **/

  public int length() {
    return size;
  }

  /**
   *  insertFront() inserts item "obj" at the beginning of this list.
   *  @param obj the item to be inserted.
   **/

  public void insertFront(Object obj) {
    head = new SListNode(obj, head);
    size++;
  }

  /**
   *  insertEnd() inserts item "obj" at the end of this list.
   *  @param obj the item to be inserted.
   **/

  public void insertEnd(Object obj) {
    if (head == null) {
      head = new SListNode(obj);
    } else {
      SListNode node = head;
      while (node.next != null) {
        node = node.next;
      }
      node.next = new SListNode(obj);
    }
    size++;
  }

  /**
   *  nth() returns the item at the specified position.  If position < 1 or
   *  position > this.length(), null is returned.  Otherwise, the item at
   *  position "position" is returned.  The list does not change.
   *  @param position the desired position, from 1 to length(), in the list.
   *  @return the item at the given position in the list.
   **/

  public Object nth(int position) {
    SListNode currentNode;

    if ((position < 1) || (head == null)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      currentNode = head;
      while (position > 1) {
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        if (currentNode == null) {
          return null;
        }
        position--;
      }
      return currentNode.item;
    }
  }

  /**
   *  squish() takes this list and, wherever two or more consecutive items are
   *  equal(), it removes duplicate nodes so that only one consecutive copy
   *  remains.  Hence, no two consecutive items in this list are equal() upon
   *  completion of the procedure.
   *
   *  After squish() executes, the list may well be shorter than when squish()
   *  began.  No extra items are added to make up for those removed.
   *
   *  For example, if the input list is [ 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 3 3 3 1 1 0 ], the
   *  output list is [ 0 1 0 3 1 0 ].
   *
   *  IMPORTANT:  Be sure you use the equals() method, and not the "=="
   *  operator, to compare items.
   **/

  public void squish() {
    // Fill in your solution here. (Ours is eleven lines long.)
      SListNode prevNode = null;
      SListNode curNode = null;
      if(size < 2){
          return;
      }
      prevNode = this.head;
      curNode = this.head.next;
      while(size >= 2){
            if(prevNode.item.equals(curNode.item)){
                prevNode.next = curNode.next;
            }else{
                prevNode = curNode;
            }

            size--;
            curNode = curNode.next;
      }

  }

  /**
   *  twin() takes this list and doubles its length by replacing each node
   *  with two consecutive nodes referencing the same item.
   *
   *  For example, if the input list is [ 3 7 4 2 2 ], the
   *  output list is [ 3 3 7 7 4 4 2 2 2 2 ].
   *
   *  IMPORTANT:  Do not try to make new copies of the items themselves.
   *  Just copy the references to the items.
   **/

  public void twin() {
    // Fill in your solution here.  (Ours is seven lines long.)
    if(size < 1)
        return;
    SListNode currentNode = this.head;
    while(currentNode != null){
        currentNode.next = new SListNode(currentNode.item, currentNode.next);
        currentNode = currentNode.next.next;
        size++;
    }
  }

  /**
   *  toString() converts the list to a String.
   *  @return a String representation of the list.
   **/

  public String toString() {
    int i;
    Object obj;
    String result = "[  ";

    SListNode cur = head;

    while (cur != null) {
      obj = cur.item;
      result = result + obj.toString() + "  ";
      cur = cur.next;
    }
    result = result + "]";
    return result;
  }

}
```

---

```
public class Homework3 {

  /**
   *  smoosh() takes an array of ints.  On completion the array contains
   *  the same numbers, but wherever the array had two or more consecutive
   *  duplicate numbers, they are replaced by one copy of the number.  Hence,
   *  after smoosh() is done, no two consecutive numbers in the array are the
   *  same.
   *
   *  Any unused elements at the end of the array are set to -1.
   *
   *  For example, if the input array is [ 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 3 3 3 1 1 0 ],
   *  it reads [ 0 1 0 3 1 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ] after smoosh()
   *  completes.
   *
   *  @param ints the input array.
   **/

  public static void smoosh(int[] a) {
    // Fill in your solution here.  (Ours is fourteen lines long, not counting
    // blank lines or lines already present in this file.)
    int currentPointer = 1;
    int i, j = 0;
    for(i =0; i < a.length; i++){
        int flag = 0;
        for(j = currentPointer; j < a.length; j++)
            if(a[j] != a[i])
            {
                a[i+1] = a[j];
                currentPointer = ++j;
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        if(j == a.length){
            if(flag == 1)
                i+=2;
            else
                i += 1;
            for(int k = i; k < a.length; k++)
                a[k] = -1;
            break;
        }
    }
  }

  /**
   *  stringInts() converts an array of ints to a String.
   *  @return a String representation of the array.
   **/

  private static String stringInts(int[] ints) {
    String s = "[  ";
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
      s = s + Integer.toString(ints[i]) + "  ";
    }
    return s + "]";
  }

  /**
   *  main() runs test cases on your smoosh and squish methods.  Prints summary
   *  information on basic operations and halts with an error (and a stack
   *  trace) if any of the tests fail.
   **/

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result;
    int i;


    System.out.println("Let's smoosh arrays!\n");

    int[] test1 = {3, 7, 7, 7, 4, 5, 5, 2, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5};
    System.out.println("smooshing " + stringInts(test1) + ":");
    smoosh(test1);
    result = stringInts(test1);
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals(
            "[  3  7  4  5  2  0  8  5  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  ]"),
                      "BAD SMOOSH!!!  No cookie.");

    int[] test2 = {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3};
    System.out.println("smooshing " + stringInts(test2) + ":");
    smoosh(test2);
    result = stringInts(test2);
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals(
            "[  6  3  6  3  6  3  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  ]"),
                      "BAD SMOOSH!!!  No cookie.");

    int[] test3 = {4, 4, 4, 4, 4};
    System.out.println("smooshing " + stringInts(test3) + ":");
    smoosh(test3);
    result = stringInts(test3);
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals("[  4  -1  -1  -1  -1  ]"),
                      "BAD SMOOSH!!!  No cookie.");

    int[] test4 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    System.out.println("smooshing " + stringInts(test4) + ":");
    smoosh(test4);
    result = stringInts(test4);
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals("[  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  ]"),
                      "BAD SMOOSH!!!  No cookie.");


    System.out.println("\nLet's squish linked lists!\n");

    int[] test5 = {3, 7, 7, 7, 4, 5, 5, 2, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5};
    SList list5 = new SList();
    for (i = 0; i < test5.length; i++) {
      list5.insertEnd(new Integer(test5[i]));
    }
    System.out.println("squishing " + list5.toString() + ":");
    list5.squish();
    result = list5.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals("[  3  7  4  5  2  0  8  5  ]"),
                      "BAD SQUISH!!!  No biscuit.");

    int[] test6 = {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3};
    SList list6 = new SList();
    for (i = 0; i < test6.length; i++) {
      list6.insertEnd(new Integer(test6[i]));
    }
    System.out.println("squishing " + list6.toString() + ":");
    list6.squish();
    result = list6.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals("[  6  3  6  3  6  3  ]"),
                      "BAD SQUISH!!!  No biscuit.");

    int[] test7 = {4, 4, 4, 4, 4};
    SList list7 = new SList();
    for (i = 0; i < test7.length; i++) {
      list7.insertEnd(new Integer(test7[i]));
    }
    System.out.println("squishing " + list7.toString() + ":");
    list7.squish();
    result = list7.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals("[  4  ]"),
                      "BAD SQUISH!!!  No biscuit.");

    int[] test8 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    SList list8 = new SList();
    for (i = 0; i < test8.length; i++) {
      list8.insertEnd(new Integer(test8[i]));
    }
    System.out.println("squishing " + list8.toString() + ":");
    list8.squish();
    result = list8.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals("[  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  ]"),
                      "BAD SQUISH!!!  No biscuit.");

    SList list9 = new SList();
    System.out.println("squishing " + list9.toString() + ":");
    list9.squish();
    result = list9.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals("[  ]"),
                      "BAD SQUISH!!!  No biscuit.");


    System.out.println("\nLet's twin linked lists!\n");

    System.out.println("twinning " + list6.toString() + ":");
    list6.twin();
    result = list6.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals(
                      "[  6  6  3  3  6  6  3  3  6  6  3  3  ]"),
                      "BAD TWIN!!!  No gravy.");

    System.out.println("twinning " + list7.toString() + ":");
    list7.twin();
    result = list7.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals("[  4  4  ]"),
                      "BAD TWIN!!!  No gravy.");

    System.out.println("twinning " + list9.toString() + ":");
    list9.twin();
    result = list9.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals("[  ]"),
                      "BAD TWIN!!!  No gravy.");
  }

}
```

---

```
public class TestHelper {

  /**
   *  verify() checks an invariant and prints an error message if it fails.
   *  If invariant is true, this method does nothing.  If invariant is false,
   *  the message is printed, followed by a dump of the program call stack.
   *
   *  @param invariant  the condition to be verified
   *  @param message  the error message to be printed if the invariant fails to
   *                  hold true.
   **/

  static void verify(boolean invariant, String message) {
    if (!invariant) {
      System.out.println("*** ERROR:  " + message);
      Thread.dumpStack();
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
class SListNode {
  Object item;
  SListNode next;


  /**
   *  SListNode() (with two parameters) constructs a list node referencing the
   *  item "obj", whose next list node is to be "next".
   */

  SListNode(Object obj, SListNode next) {
    item = obj;
    this.next = next;
  }

  /**
   *  SListNode() (with one parameter) constructs a list node referencing the
   *  item "obj".
   */

  SListNode(Object obj) {
    this(obj, null);
  }
}
```

---

Test cases:

> ```
> Let's twin linked lists!
>
> twinning [  6  3  6  3  6  3  ]:
> [  6  6  3  3  6  6  3  3  6  6  3  3  ]
> twinning [  4  ]:
> [  4  4  ]
> twinning [  ]:
> [  ]
> ```

My question:

I could make the solution for the `twin()` method in almost 7 lines (8 lines). Can we still squeeze this to 7 lines as mentioned in the comment?

Note: This code is not intend to follow OOP principles.

Comment: I guess you have missed `Do not try to make new copies of the items themselves. Just copy the references to the items.`

Comment: @Heslacher i think i handled this, i passed `currentNode.item` in the constructor

Comment: I understand that the surrounding code is prescribed by the homework skeleton, but a great part of the posted code is unrelated to your current question. For example, the smoosh() and squish() functions and the corresponding testing code are irrelevant here (and were in fact already subject of your previous questions).

Comment: @MartinR To avoid compilation errors, i pasted the complete code. If i remove smoosh(), i have to remove test case code as well before posting every query.

Comment: @overexchange please do so in the future. It's good that you posted the List and test cases in addition to the twin method, but keeping smooth, squish + test cases makes your code look like a lot more than it is, and thus complicates reviewing for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to check

```
if(size < 1)
    return;
```

Please make it a habit to never omit optional braces.  The [possibility of introducing a bug](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html) is not worth the savings of a few characters.

The loop can be written as a for-loop, and therefore probably should be:

```
public void twin() {
    for (SListNode node = this.head; node != null; node = node.next.next) {
        node.next = new SListNode(node.item, node.next);
        this.size++;
    }
}
```

Comment: while-loop is not ok? You mean for-loop is more readable in this case?

Comment: The for-loop and while-loop compile to the same bytecode. However, being able to recognize the structure of the loop just by looking at the loop header gives it an advantage in readability.

Comment: Another advantage of the `for` loop is that it helps limiting the scope of variables. In this example, `SListNode node` will only exist inside the loop itself, which eliminates a mistaken use outside of it. It can make your code more robust this way.